# Mysql fifo query stock

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, fifo

I have this mysql table
and i need a query to know available pcs of every order distinct by type.
Is it possible to do?

[image]

Must work as fifo queue
Now i need a query to know how pieces of every order are available

ES

Order Type  Available pcs

Planned     16
Cash        10

```
I buy 5 pcs with order type PLANNED      PLANNED+5
I buy 5 pcs with order type CASH         CASH+5
I buy 5 pcs with order type CASH         CASH+10
I sell 1 pcs                             PLANNED+4   
I sell 1 pcs                             PLANNED+3
1 sell 2 pcs                             PLANNED+1

I buy 15 pcs with order type PLANNED        PLANNED+16   

RESULT    PLANNED+16 CASH+10
```

Comment: 1. did you try to do something? 2. 5+15=20, why planned is 16?

Comment: Because i've buyed 5+15 products with planned order. And i sell 4 products ( FIFO mode) so i've 20-4 products available of planned orders

Comment: and where did the number 16 came from? and for the first question - did you try to write something? the question "is it possible" usually come with the answer "yes".

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Could you please explain the algorithm you call "FIFO". First in first out didn't explain that you first sold something, that you plan to buy and therefore it has to be subtracted from the planed items. Is it like that?

Comment: yes, i've written a better explicative answer. Post edited

Answer (score 2):

It this what you are looking for? Your explanation is not very clear, but this would produce the expected results for your sample data:

```
select 
    coalesce(order_type, 'PLANNED') OrderType,
    sum(case when `Buy/sell` = 'BUY' then qt else -1 * qt end) AvailablePcs
from mytable
group by coalesce(order_type, 'PLANNED')
```

Comment: Not what i need, i think i've to use a myql cursor

Comment: @MarcoTroise79: as far as concern, this solution produce the result that you expect (ie planned: 16, cash: 10)...

Comment: QUERY RESULT :  AvailablePcs;-1
    CASH;10
    PLANNED;17

Comment: QUERY RESULT :  AvailablePcs;-4
    CASH;10
    PLANNED;20